# Manipulated git in admin console - now cannot do git add from regular

Tags: git

I am running Windows. There is "nothing" running and I have a freshly booted machine.

I switched to console with admin rights and it works fine.

How do I get it back again so I don't have to use elevated privileges.

```
> git add MyPath/MyFile.cs
Rename from '.git/objects/87/tmp_obj_aYkMsa' to '.git/objects/87/f8c1884b065b8a1a62aa4131f89c5535f4e366' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
error: unable to write file .git/objects/87/f8c1884b065b8a1a62aa4131f89c5535f4e366: Permission denied
error: MyPath/MyFile.cs: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file 'MyPath/MyFile.cs'
fatal: updating files failed
```

Comment: This looks like a permissions problem. What operating system are you on? If you are on linux, do `ls -l .git/objects/87/f8c1884b065b8a1a62aa4131f89c5535f4e366` and show us the output.

Comment: Also `ls -l .git/` and `ls -l .git/objects/`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: the "try again? (y/n)" prompt thing is, I think, msysgit on Windows (and/or other Windows variants). The OP mentions Windows specifically. But yes, this is clearly some sort of permissions issue: it's a Windows problem, not a Git problem, so [tag:git] is the wrong tag.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `git` commands, Git creates, reads, and edits files under the `.git` folder. If you run these commands as an administrator account, you will create files that are owned by that administrator. I think you did this in your situation. Now your regular user doesn't have permissions to write, modify, or delete those files. To fix the problem, you need to change ownership of all files under `.git` to your regular user. I'm not familiar with doing this on Windows, so I can only refer you to other online resources to see how to do this. For example, [this page](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-server-cookbook/0596006330/ch04s18.html) seems to be what you need.